# Am I misusing dimens.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

This will be a pretty simple question, because I might have been doing the wrong thing for a long time.
I will introduce my problem with an example: Let's say that the designer defines the following design for a screen of our app (phone only):

[image]

Which I then would implement with the following layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="56sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Which looks fine on the Nexus 5, but when I switch to a Nexus One, I get this picture, which is definitely not what I wanted:

[image]

So my solution for this was: defining a dimens.xml both in */values*, and in */values-sw360dp*. Then adding a dimension for the text size. Where the size would be 56sp in *values-sw360dp/dimens.xml*, and 52sp in *values/dimens.xml*
Of course, when the project got bigger and bigger, the amount of dimens just kept rising (we have about a hundred now). It's not only text sizes of course, but widths, heights, margins and paddings too.

Lately I got a remark, which said that keeping track of all the dimens is just hell, because sometimes you forget to edit one (like when making something smaller), and then it looks good on all screen sizes except one. I completely agree with this, but can't think of a better solution. Is this what dimens.xml is for, or is there a way better solution I just didn't find yet?

Comment: With respect to text size, you are welcome to use any number of libraries that can automatically adjust the font scale, [such as `AutoSizeTextView`](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/473). 
With respect to "margins and paddings", those are usually handled by dimension resources, akin to handling them in CSS rules in Web development. Beyond that, design fluid layouts (so you can hard-code fewer "heights, widths") that can handle word-wrap (particularly for text not knowable in advance, such as user-entered values or data retrieved from the Internet).

Comment: It's really not just text, this was just a good example of showing the difference. By saying *those are usually handled by dimension resources*, do you mean dimens.xml, or something other?

Comment: Dimension resources are `<dimen>` elements in a `res/values*/` file. By convention, that file is named `dimens.xml`, but it does not have to be.

Comment: Alright, now I understand. If you post your first comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get this picture, which is definitely not what I wanted

I am going to guess that you mean that you do not want this text to be word-wrapped.

> is there a way better solution I just didn't find yet?

With respect to text size, you are welcome to use any number of libraries that can automatically adjust the font scale, [such as `AutoSizeTextView`](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/473).

With respect to "margins and paddings", those are usually handled by dimension resources, akin to handling them in CSS rules in Web development.

Beyond that, design fluid layouts (so you can hard-code fewer "heights, widths") that can handle word-wrap (particularly for text not knowable in advance, such as user-entered values or data retrieved from the Internet).

> It's really not just text, this was just a good example of showing the difference.

Most widgets don't have "word wrap" as an option; for those, you really need to use fluid layout designs, where the size of the widget is derived at runtime from other rules (`wrap_content`, `match_parent`, weights on `LinearLayout`, spanning rules on `GridLayout`, anchoring rules on `RelativeLayout`, column-sizing rules on `TableLayout`, etc.).